# Empty field control is valid when validators are set to minLength

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have created a form with a controlforms.

```
idAnnuaire: new FormControl('',[Validators.minLength(6),Validators.maxLength(6)]),
```

the problem is that when the field is empty `{{form.controls.idAnnuaire.valid }}`
 is set to `true`. ( Expecting false )

I would not set the controlform to required because user can send form if he fill the other inputs instead of `idAnnuaire`

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-i89eig?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Its working fine because you have set `minLength` not `required` so if user type somthing it will check for validation else not

Comment: actually If the user don't type anything  I get .valid = true ( and here's the problem ), when he type from 1 to 5 or >6 caracter it's false, else true.

Comment: could you reproduce your problem on stackblitz.com?

Comment: add Validators.required

Comment: @PardeepJain added the issue reproduction

Comment: @infodev as per your code you allow user to bypass if he not want to fill this field and if he want then you set condition, so as per validation its working fine. either add `Validators.required`

Comment: Yes he can bypass because in my local code there are other inputs that he can fill instead of this one. if I set this field to required, the formgroup will not be valid if users fill other inputs and not this one, and it's not what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions to this - however, I think the best choice for this specific scenario is to create a custom validator. It could look something like this:

```js
// Custom Validator file

// Uncomment this for the actual app - commented out for the snippet
// import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

// This should be removed - the acutal value should come from the form
const inputValidValue = { value: '123123' };
const inputInvalidValueLow = { value: '123' };
const inputInvalidValueHigh = { value: '123123123123' };
const inputInvalidValueNoValue = { value: '' };

// this needs to be an exported function - snippet wont run if 'export' is there 
function validateOptionalFieldWithLength(input){
  return validateField(input, { validField: true });
}

// Uncomment this for the actual app - commented out for the snippet
// function validateField(input: FormControl, error: { [errorKey: string]: boolean }) {
function validateField(input, error) {
  let isValidField = true;
  let fieldValue = input.value;

if (fieldValue && fieldValue.length === 6 ) {
    return null;
  }
  return error;
}


console.log('should be valid (null) : ' + validateOptionalFieldWithLength(inputValidValue));
console.log('should be invalid (error) : ' + validateOptionalFieldWithLength(inputInvalidValueLow));
console.log('should be invalid (error) : ' + validateOptionalFieldWithLength(inputInvalidValueHigh));
console.log('should be invalid (error) : ' + validateOptionalFieldWithLength(inputInvalidValueNoValue));
```

```js
// You component

// Import your custom validator


idAnnuaire: new FormControl('', 
              Validators.compose([
                validateOptionalFieldWithLength
              ])
            )
```

Comment: thanks ,could  it be working if using validators.pattern also ?

Comment: Yea - it could work with a pattern as well - a custom validator would be able to be used in multiple places (if needed) without having to copy / paste your regex. 

Here is a stackblitz of the custom validator off of your posted above:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-i89eig

Comment: @infodev

Your regex would look like this: (^$|^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$)

Here is a stackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-i89eig

Comment: you could also use a constant regex file to reuse throughout the app and not have to copy your regex every time